# Implementing payment method per currency

Tags: store-view, currency, internationalization

Is it possible to implement a payment method per currency level? The site in question needs to accept both USD and Indian Rupee. When a client pays with USD, it needs to be connected to a US bank/payment method, when paying with Indian Rupee, it needs to be connected to an Indian bank/payment method.

The site scope will be: one domain; one language; two currencies.

Is the above model feasible or it's better to stick to a multi-store or better alternative? e.g.

- site.com/en
- site.com/in

Comment: I think better you manage two store views for each country and two payment methods against each as well

Comment: @Sukeshini That might hinder the user experience a little. Thoughts?

Comment: You can only checkout in base currency, you need two separate website views and enable Website Pricing instead of Global.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using Event observer.
Create config.xml under app/code/local/Bh>ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>etc.
code of this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <class>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model</class>
            </zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/observer</class>
                        <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create Observer.php under app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model/
code is

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();


        if($method->getCode()=='paypal_standard')
        {   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()=='INR'){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        if($method->getCode()=='free'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()=='USD'){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

In My example i have disabled `paypal standard payment method when Current currency code is INR` and ccavluenue for Current Currency code is USD

Comment: How to add filter selected customer group only view selected payment gateway? @Amit Bera♦

Answer (score 0):

I would scope both language and currency at the store view level.  So in your case you would have 2 store views, both with english language, each with different currency specs.  You could make language be store level but I think you may find that you want to reserve store level for a different, more general grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your store in this format, you can achieve it easily

> **WEBSITE :** YOUR WEBSITE

```
STORES(2)

  - AMERICA

       STOREVIEWS(1)

           - English


  - INDIA(1)

        STOREVIEWS(1)

           - English
```

Everything except payment method should set same for two stores and then set different payment methods for each store.

Hope it helps

Comment: That was one way I was thinking of approaching it but how can I utilize the currency. For example, it would be great when a shopper switches the currency, the page redirects to "currency" store.