# displaying certain payment methods for customer groups

Tags: checkout, magento-1, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment

I am very new to the magento checkout process so forgive my lack of knowledge. Is there a way of displaying certain payment options for certain customer groups. For example i have changed the "purchase order number" to "30 day credit account" but this is only available to a certain customer group so I only want it to display when the user is logged in and is part of that customer group.

Again sorry for my lack of knowledge, if you can help you would be a life saver.

Thank you

Comment: upvote from me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do this using magento `event observer,create an event on payment_method_is_active` and depednds on customer group disable and enable payment method:

check this link:
[Implementing payment method per currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24447/implementing-payment-method-per-currency/24502#)

and you need `do  on some change in observer.php`
I have trying to example  and try to modify according to  you

```
   public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

 $roleId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
 $role = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($roleId)->getData('customer_group_code');

      if($method->getCode()=='purchaseorder'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

            if($role == $yourcustomergroupid){
              $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
              $result->isAvailable = true;
              return;
            }else{
               $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
               $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }

     if($method->getCode()=='checkmo'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

            if($role == $yourcustomergroupid){
              $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
              $result->isAvailable = true;
            return;
            }else{
              $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
              $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
}

}
```

**Note: If you not getting customer group id from session then you need  tp load  customer by customer id(which is must get from session)** 
 for getting customer group from  session try below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242390/showing-which-group-a-customer-belongs-to-in-magento
http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2010/12/get-customer-group-id-in-magento.html

Let me know if you have any confusion

Comment: do i put the observer in another directory called model?

Comment: you need to create Observer.php at app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model/ ... and just change  in filterpaymentmethod

Comment: also create the config under /etc. do i need to create a new .xml file in app/etc/modules/ as well? Thank you for your patience as well :)

Comment: config.xml under app/code/local/Bh>ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>etc.

Comment: create Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod.xml  on app/etc/modules/

Comment: it code     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
 <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
  <active>true</active>
  <codePool>local</codePool>
 </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
</modules>
</config>

Comment: @AmitBera Excellent as usual +1. Thanks

Comment: I want to restrict a particular customer from cod? Is there any solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use the extension and its working fine for customer group and also filter by product and its free:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paymentfilter-for-products-and-customer-groups.html

Answer (score 4):

**In Magento 2**

Let’s create a module.
Step 1) Create folders like this.

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/Observer/
```

Step 2) Declare your module

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/module.xml.
```

Paste the following code in the above file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pits_PaymentMethod" setup_version="2.0.0" /></config>
```

Step 4 ) Create registration file.
        **app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/registration.php**
Paste the below code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pits_PaymentMethod',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 5)Run the below command in the command line

php bin/magento module:enable Pits_PaymentMethod

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Step 6)Lets create events.xml file

app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/etc/events.xml

Paste the below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="Pits_PaymentMethod_DisabledPgByCustomergroup" instance="Pits\PaymentMethod\Observer\DisabledPgByCustomergroup" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Step 7)Lets create observer file

```
app/code/Pits/PaymentMethod/Observer/DisabledPgByCustomergroup.php.php



<?php
namespace Pits\PaymentMethod\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class DisabledPgByCustomergroup implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());
        /* If Cusomer  group is match then work */
        if (null !== $quote && $quote->getCustomerGroupId() != 4) {
            /* Disable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
            if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'purchaseorder') {
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
            }
        }
        /*else{
        if($method_instance->getCode() =='purchaseorder'){
        $result->setData('is_available', true);

        }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Step 8)Run this in command line

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this extension :

http://amasty.com/shipping-payment-by-customer-group.html by [@Amasty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12293/amasty)

Allow you filter payment methods and shipping methods by customer groups

Answer (score 0):

This free extensions will help you out:

https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter