# Magento 1.9 - Simple code for enable Payment method for a Customer Group

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, payment-methods, customer-group

I write because I wanted to see if it was possible to enable a type of payment method like the "check / money order" just for a specific group of customers.

My idea was to enable, from the backend, the "check / money order", then go to the file that showed on the checkout page and then hide it with an if in php.

My question was, in what page I can set the if?

Otherwise to show this type of payment only for a specific group of customers how could I do?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Past this code in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Checkmo.php

```
$isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
/* If customer is logged in */
if($isLoggedIn) :
    /* Get the logged in customer's group ID */
    $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    /* Check if the logged in customer's group ID matches with the ID you are after */
    /* Customer group IDs are listed against each group under Admin > Customers > Customer Groups */
    if($customerGroupId == 8) :

    ****Content of class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Checkmo extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract****

endif;
endif;
```

in this way the type of payment can be viewed only customer ID group that you want .

Comment: I have two payment gateway, one payment gateway for one dedicated customer, how to add condition for that. eg:  Arun (arun@gmail) can able to pay via both payment gateway other customer only one payment gateway to pay.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your field by a custom system.xml which adds this field and you need to observe the event `payment_method_is_active`declared in Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract line 660-675. In your observer you need to do the check for the allowed customer groups. 
Or you use the following extension: https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter

Comment: There is a good guide where I can follow precisely these passages? The extension, for now, I prefer not to use it. Thank you.

Comment: You can have a look into the code of the extension. However it assigns the payment methods to customer groups (which is a more generic approach), see `https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter/blob/master/app/code/community/RicoNeitzel/PaymentFilter/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Form.php` and for the filtering see `https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter/blob/master/app/code/community/RicoNeitzel/PaymentFilter/Model/Observer.php` lines 144-174.

Comment: The two links are not valid...Could you paste it again please? Thanks.

Comment: Strange direct linking to the files does not work. Hoever if you open the link to the extension above] you can navigate to the files.

Comment: Or you can look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups

Comment: Please let me know if there's some confusion left or mark the question as solved. 
Thanks.

Comment: Hello Michael, exscusme but I have returned to this work today because I Had Other commitments . However , the last link you sent me I have already tried but without success. I think that the problem is that does not feel my observer.php costumes Even if I insert it in the right folder . Question , in this case my observer.php I must totally create it from zero ? What class can i include my code? Thank you so much for all clarification

Comment: Close the question please. I found the solution!!! I created an if for customer group id and i entered into the file Checkmo.php, outside the class! Thanks for any help and for the patience. ;)

Comment: You can close it by setting your question to answered.