# Show /Hide my custom payment method - (offline) at checkout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, custom

I need to hide custom offline payment method according to customer Groups! how to achieve this
?

Comment: I think http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups link might be useful.

Comment: Its for magento 1.9, I need in magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add this code in our Namespace/Modulename/Model/ in file.php

```
 public function isActive($storeId = null)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerGroupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        if ($customerGroupId != 4) {
            return false;
        }
        return (bool)(int)$this->getConfigData('active', $storeId);
    }
```

Comment: can you explain this for bank transfer method I want to show only specific customer to bank transfer method. can you post the steps.