# How to disable Cash On Delivery on specific customers in using magento 2.1.3?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, cash-on-delivery

Customer for COD and return order three time, make him as blacklist and for his new order COD should be disable.

Answer (score 0):

Best workaround is create a customer group and add user / customer into that group, this will be easier to implement rather then picking individual user one by one and check if payment method is enable or not.

here you can find helpful stuff to implement it :
[displaying certain payment methods for customer groups](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups)