# How to restrict payment methods by store?

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-methods

I want to restrict the payment method by store.How to do this?

Eg.

For English version I need 3 payment modules

```
1.Paypal 
2. cod 
3.Bank transfer
```

For Other version I need 1 payment method

```
1.Paypal
```

alone

How to achieve this?

Comment: Goto admin>System>Configuration>change Current scope  according store then Payment Method and  disable from here

Comment: There is no option for disabling in magento

Answer (score 3):

Do this using *event observer*. Create an observer for the event `payment_method_is_active` and depends on current store disable and enable payment method:

See there: [Implementing payment method per currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24447/implementing-payment-method-per-currency/24502#)

And you need change on observer.In below example i have disable payment zero subtotal check when current store code  is default

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        /* this condtion prevent zero payment to display when current store is not default */
        if ($method->getCode()=='free' &&  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()!='deafult') {
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if (Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal())>0) {
                $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
                $result->isAvailable = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Here you need put your logic

Comment: Nice answer @amit :)

Comment: why down vote? who give this downvote.please explain

Comment: I have don't give down vote

Comment: it is so irritating me..

Comment: Don't irritating bro :)

Answer (score 3):

So from what I can see the code will allow for different store values for all the config attributes, so active etc...but Magento by default only allows you to do it for the labels.

```
public function getConfigData($field, $storeId = null)
{
    if (null === $storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->getStore();
    }
    $path = 'payment/'.$this->getCode().'/'.$field;
    return Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $storeId);
}
```

What you could do is create and extension that updates the node value for the payment methods from `<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>` to `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>`

This should then allow the attribute to be set via the admin on the store level.

**Note: I have not tested this but looking through the code this should work**

Your system.xml file for allowing the ccsave method on store level would look like:

```
<config>
   <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <ccsave>
                    <fields>
                        <active>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                    </fields>
                </ccsave>
            </groups>
        </payment>
   </sections>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the option to enable and disable this payment method, show_in_store is 1

Example:

```
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

Then you just change the store enable or disable each means of payment by store

Answer (score -1):

Magento By default Provide this kind of functionality.

**Step 1:** Go to `system >> Configuration >> Payment Methods >> Select Bank Transfer Tab`.

**Step 2:** Now you have to select `Payment from Applicable Countries` to `Specific Country`.

**Step 3:** Select `Payment from Specific Countries` to country and Save configuration.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now Refresh cache and check Checkout Step.

Let me know if any comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I need for specific store not for specific country.Can you help for this