# Hide the Payment method based on store view

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, store-view

we selected store views under `Current Configuration Scope:`

[image]

Than we went under `Advanced > Advanced > Disable Module output`

we disabled the custom **payment method** modules

but after that also for that store view, those disabled payment methods are displaying.

when i thought to try by going Payment methods & disbale it, those custom payment methods are not visible for store view.

Payu & HDFC is visible for `Default config`

[image]

Payu & HDFC is not visible for `store -view`

[image]

entire module code [here](http://www.filedropper.com/integrationkitv3hdfcmagento190)

Comment: This should be work.May some Customization in your system that why it happen

Comment: is their no option to disable method @ Sales->Payment Method

Comment: @AmitBera its happening for 2 custom payment method modules - both provide by official team - `payu & hdfc`

Comment: @AshishMadankar  under `Sales->Payment Method` those payment methods are not visible once i select the store view.

Comment: Please see here @AmitBera answer may be it will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/36889/21339

Comment: Please share  your module code.May be at Payment gatewatt method class .. have isseue

Comment: @AmitBera please download entire module code [here](http://www.filedropper.com/integrationkitv3hdfcmagento190)

Comment: in your `app\code\core\Mage\Hdfc\etc\system.xml`  replace `<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>` with `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>` and check if it work or not ?

Comment: @AshishMadankar peRFect, let me check for other module.

Comment: @AshishMadankar smae logic for other module, worked fine. what you waiting for, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each module their visibility for different scope are specified in `system.xml` in your case it is @ `app\code\core\Mage\Hdfc\etc\system.xml` by

`<show_in_default>` to make visible in **Default Config Mode**.

`<show_in_website>` to make visible in **Website Mode**.

`<show_in_store>` to make visible in **Store View Mode**.

just replace `<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>` with `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>`

Hope this helps you.