# Payment methods based on billing region?

Tags: payment, regions

What I need to do is to display different payment methods based on billing regions. Magento has built in the option to display different payment methods based on the country. So my question is this can be made to display different methods of payment depending on the region of the country. For example, if I have country x with payment methods pay1 pay2 pay3, for the region y of this country I want to be only pay1 and pay2.

It would be better if I didn't modify any core files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii ,Do this using event observer

Create an event on payment_method_is_active and depends region  on  disable and enable payment method:

See at [Implementing payment method per currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24447/implementing-payment-method-per-currency/24502#)

and just need change observer

create config.xml under :**`app/code/community/Devamitbera/Statewisecod/etc/config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
*/-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <statewisecod>
                <class>Devamitbera_Statewisecod_Model</class>
            </statewisecod>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend> <!--  run observer  event for frontend -->
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <enable_cod_for_some_state>
                        <class>statewisecod/observer</class>
                        <method>EnableCod</method>
                    </enable_cod_for_some_state>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Create observer file 
under **Observer.php** under **`app/code/community/Devamitbera/Statewisecod/Model`**

**Code  of this file:**

```
  <?php
class Devamitbera_Statewisecod_Model_Observer
{
    public function EnableCod($observer){
        $result=$observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $MethodInstance=$observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if($quote && $quote->getId()):
        /* If Payment method is  cashondelivery  then  conitnue  */
            if($MethodInstance->getCode()=='cashondelivery'){
                #Mage::log('Payment is Cod',null,'Cod.log',true);
                $ShippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();

                /* region_id is working when country have  
                * drop state/regions.
                */
                /* Here i  have put USA coutry new work & Washinton redion */

                #Mage::log('redion'.$ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),null,'redion.log',true);

                $CodEnableRegionIds=array(62,43);
                if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),$CodEnableRegionIds)):
                      $result->isAvailable=true;
                elseif(is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegionId()) && !is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegion())):
                /* This section working when State/region is not dropdown 
                 and state is dropdown
                */
                $textListRegionName=array('West bengal','Delhi');
                    if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegion(),$textListRegionName)){
                          $result->isAvailable=true;
                    }else{
                          $result->isAvailable=false;
                    }
                else:
                  $result->isAvailable=false;
                endif;              


                return   $result->isAvailable;
            }

        endif;


    }
}
```

create module file  `Devamitbera_Statewisecod.xml` under `app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
-->
<config>
    <modules>
    <Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
        <depends><Mage_Payment/></depends>
    </Devamitbera_Statewisecod>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here `cashondelivery` is payment method `code of cash on delivery`.... which is saved in database.

### - Edited:

**region_id** is working when country have   *drop state/regions list*.

```
if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegionId(),$CodEnableRegionIds)):
                      $result->isAvailable=true;
```

If  **State/region** is not **dropdown then Below logic is work**

```
elseif(is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegionId()) && !is_null($ShippingAddress->getRegion())):
$textListRegionName=array('West bengal','Delhi');
    if(in_array($ShippingAddress->getRegion(),$textListRegionName)){
      $result->isAvailable=true;
    }else{
      $result->isAvailable=false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried it but nothing happens, how can i try if it is implemented ok? i made several var_dump but nothing shows up..

Comment: have you follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24447/implementing-payment-method-per-currency/24502# link to create extension?

Comment: Does this work for one page checkout ?

Comment: of course.. it will work