# how to set payment method based on country in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, web-services

i am creating a webservice . so i want to set payment method for magento v1.9 based on country details and cash on delivery(cod) for particular products and particular country in magento . how to set programmatically?

Comment: do you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

First checkout this link [Payment methods based on billing region?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43880/payment-methods-based-on-billing-region/43881#43881)

For your your case, at **`Devamitbera_Statewisecod_Model_Observer`** class on function **EnableCod** function,you can your logic basic of ur require.

At *this function you can current quote item from* *`$quote->getAllItems()`*.

```
$Items=$quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($Items as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

**Now this code,you can do whatever,what u want.**

Please let me know if any help u need from me

Comment: Hi what method(POST or GET) is this webservice?